# Screenshot is not getting generated on test failure even if the code for taking screenshot is correct in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have attached a hook for taking screenshot whenever it encounters a failure and it will attach the screenshot to the report. But, on failure, the screenshot is not getting generated and on clicking the screenshot, the error is coming as 'Your file couldn’t be accessed. It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND'

Attaching the hook which was able to capture screenshot successfully. But, now it is not getting generated.

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    """
        Extends the PyTest Plugin to take and embed screenshot in html report, whenever test fails.
        :param item:
        """
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == 'call' or report.when == "setup":
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace("::", "_") + ".png"
            _capture_screenshot(file_name)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                       'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra


def _capture_screenshot(name):
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the path from where to take the screenshots I use something like this:

```
def remove_files():
    download_path = r'E:\iollo\food-generation-ocb-automation-a36cc1ff0a57\scrennshot\**\*.png'
    return download_path
```

Here I add a path to downloaded the screenshots in a folder and than I use the fixture to add the path in the report.

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        feature_request = item.funcargs['request']
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            feature_request = item.funcargs["request"]
            driver = feature_request.getfixturevalue("setup")
            timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')
            path = "/oalaCuBunatati"
            ismount= os.path.ismount(path)
            img_name = "name" + timestamp + ".png"
            # img_path = os.path.join("D:\GIT\ocb-automation\scrennshot", img_name)
            img_path = os.path.join(r'/oalaCuBunatati/scrennshot', img_name)
            driver.save_screenshot(img_path)


        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # only add additional html on failure
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(img_path))
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
        report.extra = extra
```

Maybe this will help you, in this way I use to generate the screenshots into html